# Does the secure WebSockets wss:// protocol encrypt client-to-server data?

Tags: ssl, websocket, socket.io, wss

From my understanding, HTTPS only encrypts data being sent from the server to the client and does NOT encrypt data being sent from the client to the server.

After about two hour of research, **I can't find out if WSS also encrypts data being sent from the client to the server.** I know that it encrypts the data being from the server to the client like HTTPS.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. HTTPS is HTTTP over SSL, which encrypts in both directions. A 'secure' protocol wouldn't be secure without that.

Comment: I don't know why I remember being told that https is only encrypted from server to client... Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both HTTPS and WSS use SSL/TLS. SSL/TLS encrypts all data inside the connection, i.e. data from server to client and from client to server.

Comment: This answer would be better with a reference on wss that shows this.

Comment: @jfriend00: why do you expect a reference that `wss://` is `ws://` over SSL/TLS but not that `https://` is `http://` over SSL/TLS?  But here you have it: [RFC 6456 (WebSockets) Section 11.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-11.1.2): *Registration of "wss" Scheme ...indicates that traffic over that connection is to be protected via
   TLS ...*

Comment: Because then people learn how to go find these things for themselves and learn where these kinds of answers come from.  Besides answers like this with references are almost always better than answers without them.  No need to get defensive.  I was making a suggestion for how to improve your answer.  It's not like I downvoted you or anything.

Comment: I don't know why I remember being told that https is only encrypted from server to client...